# What's the possible problem of unable to handle kernel paging request

Tags: crash

Can't get longer error, since the system crash/hang:

```
Jun 02 08:09:45 G4560 kernel: BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff8e342f9f5c00
Jun 02 08:09:45 G4560 kernel: IP: get_futex_value_locked+0x5/0x40
```

Sometimes it shows something like this (and hang):

[image: screen fragment]

Using 64-bit ubuntu 18.04, linux-4.15.0-101

using Intel G4560, ASrock Z170 Gaming K6

**Additional Info #1** (as requested on the comment)

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           62Gi        11Gi        31Gi       2,1Gi        19Gi        48Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi

$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb5: UUID="48c76170-0392-44ce-a8c6-f790673c8f32" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0e14aa1d-05"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="S2T1bad" UUID="9ccaf888-65f7-4679-a36a-f5b61fb17473" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00088c2e-01"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="EB85-DF8F" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="0e14aa1d-01"
/dev/sdd2: LABEL="W3T" UUID="142849d7-f252-4445-aa2e-d80025a07def" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2d9c04cd-6e9b-4067-b065-7c90596175c8"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="W3T41bad" UUID="94bd95c8-3466-427c-9073-447a79a2b903" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1d6c10c6-a6c1-4a25-a80f-6afb1ae74a5e"
/dev/sde2: LABEL="M320G" UUID="21062e0c-21e4-4b34-a674-4b807059837e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0001f386-02"
/dev/sdf1: LABEL="W8T1bad" UUID="f7cbc067-26d5-4115-a539-4527a9e834fc" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7ff0ed9e-63ad-4594-b572-34d41ed93933"
/dev/sdg1: LABEL="W8T" UUID="afebff04-ed3f-4987-8783-1eb722a22554" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0c648df4-3dee-44fd-861c-946c7d9bb4c4"
/dev/sdh1: LABEL="w8tnew" UUID="998bec6f-4b11-4bb3-a878-8529c0a8c11d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2a7bf730-db0a-4586-919b-baf6c2979084"
/dev/sdi1: LABEL="L1" UUID="01492680-b253-45fe-a234-6710e50eb8bf" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5f67ac6c-9b52-4c98-a9ed-102911559294"
```

the RAM Already tested with [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) all 13 test x 2 pass without error.

**Additional Info #2**

was froze again but without screen fragment, when using:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
P7.40

$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-33-generic Tue Jun  2 20:04 - 12:11  (16:07) --> froze (without screen fragment)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-33-generic Tue Jun  2 20:01 - 12:11  (16:10)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-33-generic Tue Jun  2 09:23 - 12:56  (03:32)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-33-generic Tue Jun  2 08:32 - 09:22  (00:50) --> froze (without screen fragment)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-101-gener Tue Jun  2 08:24 - 08:31  (00:07)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-101-gener Tue Jun  2 07:29 - 08:31  (01:02) --> froze (with screen fragment)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-101-gener Tue Jun  2 06:48 - 08:31  (01:43)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-32-generi Tue Jun  2 06:24 - 06:47  (00:23)
```

currently updated to latest BIOS and available kernel, also updated to Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
P7.50

$ uname -a
Linux G4560 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`.

Comment: added @heynnema , previously the RAM was only 16GB, but it is fresh install ubuntu 18.04 (about a year ago and never use the PC until now, since my laptop died this morning), now I updated to 20.04

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me your make/model # of computer, or if this is a custom build, is ASrock Z170 Gaming K6 the correct model #?

Comment: @heynnema it's P7.40, ok i'll try update the bios

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema havent crashed again, for now.. it's a bit random anyway

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema nearly 4 days, no error (yet) :3 thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASrock Z170 Gaming K6

You have BIOS version P7.40, dated 3/12/2018.

There's a newer BIOS, version 7.50 available, dated 10/26/2018, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Fatal1ty%20Z170%20Gaming%20K6/#BIOS).

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.